# Variance of a symmetric random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, random-variable

Let say I have a multivariate random variable $x$ with dimension $s$ which is symmetric at 0 and not necessarily be a multivariate normal distribution. Then what is the variance of $Ax$, where $A$ is a full-rank square matrix with dimension $s$? Is it $AxA'$?

Comment: No need for symmetry in this formula: $\mathbb{V}[\mathbf A \mathbf x] = \mathbf A \mathbb{V}[\mathbf x] \mathbf A^\top$ (also no need for the matrix to be square or of full rank).